# How to join two groupby dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a left join on a groupby result with another groupby result:

```
group1=table1.groupby(['Country','Year','Adjustment'],as_index=False)
group2=table2.groupby(['location','year','cause',as_index=False)
result=pd.merge(group1,group2,left_on=['Country','Year','Adjustment'],right_on=['location','year','cause'],how='left')
```

this is the error I get:

> can not merge DataFrame with instance of type class 'pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'

I did not find a solution online. I found a similar question where the solution suggests to use `to_frame()`, but it did not work.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Ron

Comment: You have a missing `]` on the second group by. Is this present in your code or just a copy error?

Comment: Thanks, but was only a typo.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate 2 dataframes you us `pd.concat()` function.
try:

```
pd.concat([group1,group2], axis=0)
```

`axis = 0` or `axis = 1` as per your choice.. `axis = 1` will append data as columns. `axis = 0` will append data as rows

Comment: thanks, but the new error is: _cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>";_ Also, I doubt that it would return all possible combinations of the join. My dataframe includes in reality more columns and I realized that it works if I add `.count()` to my grouping. However, I do not understand why this is necessary. What I am trying to do would be a simple task in SQL...

Comment: The thing is when you group a dataset you need to mention group by what funtion(like objective).. Suppose I have a dataset... person name and nationality. Now if I want to group the data such that I display only nationalities then what it does is takes unique values from Nationality col but it doesn't know what to do with other coloumns so you ask it to perform a function over other couloums as per your objective.. you have various functions to use... like ```.count()```, ```.sum()```, ```.mean()```.....each have their own use to analyze data. and these operations will be performed on othr col

Comment: .count() on the above dataset(I mentioned) will list one col with nationalities with each row unique and the next coloumn will be a count of that nationality person name occurance